# Displaying image from XML

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsxmlparser, nsdata, nsurl

I'm using `NSXMLParser` and I want to display images from XML as a `<url>` node using `UITableViewCell`.

Inside the table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I'm using this code:

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                           objectForKey:@"url"]];

NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

UIImage * newsPhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

cell.imageView.image = newsPhoto;
```

But the image never shows up.  I can see the result in the log.

Please advise.